# Linux 'cut' command line and replace

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I need to create some text using `cut` command and replace with space, on  Linux terminal.

Examples:

```
Linux
 inux
  nux
   ux
    x
```

---

This is my bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT=$@
SIZE=$(echo $INPUT|wc -c)
let $((SIZE--))
for i in $(seq 1 $SIZE);
do echo $INPUT | cut -c ${i}-${SIZE} ;
done
```

and i have failed to create some text like :

```
Linux
 inux
  nux
   ux
    x
```

Comment: How did you decide that `cut` was the right tool?

Comment: i mean, on unix command line / bash / terminal.

Comment: Was that supposed to be an answer to my question?!

Comment: Probably homework. Tell us what you've tried so far. What does `man cut` tell you?

Comment: Oh.. sorry @Biffen i'm not foccus at your answer. or may you have right tool?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Give a simple example of a source string and the desired output string.

Comment: `python -c "for n in range(len('Linux')): print ' ' * n, 'Linux'[n:len('Linux')]"`

Comment: Hi @ArnonZilca this sample code :  #!/bin/bash
INPUT=$@
SIZE=$(echo $INPUT|wc -c)
let $((SIZE--))
for i in $(seq 1 $SIZE);
do echo $INPUT | cut -c ${i}-${SIZE} ;
done

Comment: `string="Linux" ; while [[ -n "${string// /}" ]] ; do echo "${string}" ; string="$(echo "${string}" | sed 's/\S/ /')" ; done`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT="$@"
SIZE=${#INPUT}

for ((i=0; i < ${SIZE}; i++)); do
    echo "${INPUT}"
    INPUT="${INPUT:0:${i}} ${INPUT:$((i+1)):${SIZE}}"
    #INPUT="$(echo "$INPUT" | sed "s/^\(.\{${i}\}\)./\1 /")"
done
```

I added a `sed` option in the comment, although it creates a sub-process when you don't really have to.